# Summing odd integers from an Array in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

```
inputs = [
  ["9", "5", "4"],
  ["20", "40", "60"],
  ["1", "3", "19"]
]
numbers = inputs.sample
pp numbers
```

I’m trying to figure out how to add only the odd integers in the array together. So whenever I run the test, it’ll choose from the 3 rows and add them together.

I attempted to do it with an .each method to loop each integer but I keep running into errors.

```
sum = 0
numbers.each  { |num| sum = num}
if  pp num.to_i.odd?
    pp num.to_i 
end
```

Comment: The sum off the odd numbers in any of the sample inputs.

Comment: "I keep running into errors" is not a precise enough problem description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? What is the error message? Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases?

Comment: Please, also make sure to provide a [mre]. https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/

Answer (score 4):

Ruby `Array` has a method called [`sum`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.2/Array.html#method-i-sum).

You can pass a block to this method and it will "sum" (quotes are because `Array#sum` is not limited to the mathematical definition of sum) up the result of that block so in your case this can be boiled down to:

```
inputs = [
  ["9", "5", "4"],
  ["20", "40", "60"],
  ["1", "3", "19"]
]
inputs.sample.sum {|e| e.to_i.odd? ? e.to_i : 0 }
```

In this case (using the ternary operator)  if `e.to_i` is an odd number then we return that number otherwise we return `0`. This equates to the following for each know input:

- `["9", "5", "4"]` -> `[9,5,0].sum`
- `["20", "40", "60"]` -> `[0,0,0].sum`
- `["1", "3", "19"]` -> `[1,3,19].sum`

There are umpteen other ways to accomplish this goal in Ruby using any number of [`Enumerable`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.2/Enumerable.html) methods. (e.g. `map`, `select`, `filter_map`, `inject`, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

There are several problems with your attempt.

First of all, `sum = num` will *assign* `num` to `sum`, thus overwriting its previous value:

```
sum = 0
sum = "9"
sum #=> "9"

sum = "5"
sum #=> "5"
```

It's not enough to name the variable `sum`, you have to *add* `num` to `sum` in order to get an actual sum. This can be done via `sum = sum + 9` (add `9` to the current value of `sum` and assign the result back to `sum`) or the shorthand `sum += 9`. However, since `num` is – despite its name – a string, you have to convert it to an integer beforehand:

```
sum = 0
sum += "9".to_i
sum #=> 9

sum += "5".to_i
sum #=> 14
```

Inside a loop:

```
sum = 0
nums.each do |num|
  sum += num.to_i
end
```

Next, your condition `if num.to_i.odd?` is executed *after* the loop and it won't affect the sum in any way. You should move it *inside* the loop to only add the numbers that are odd:

```
sum = 0
nums.each do |num|
  if num.to_i.odd?
    sum += num.to_i
  end
end
```

There's also a [modifier-`if`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-Modifier+if+and+unless) which can be appended to an expression:

```
sum = 0
nums.each do |num|
  sum += num.to_i if num.to_i.odd?
end
```

And you could also use a so-called *guard clause* to skip elements that aren't odd via [`next`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-next+Statement):

```
sum = 0
nums.each do |num|
  next unless num.to_i.odd?

  sum += num.to_i
end
```

A more structured approach would be to first [`map`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/Array.html#method-i-map) all strings to their integer counterparts, to [`select`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/Array.html#method-i-select) the odd ones and to finally sum them using the built-in [`sum`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/Array.html#method-i-sum) method:

```
nums = ["9", "5", "4"]

nums.map { |num| num.to_i }    #=> [9, 5, 4]
    .select { |num| num.odd? } #=> [9, 5]
    .sum                       #=> 14
```

Which can be shortened to:

```
nums.map(&:to_i).select(&:odd?).sum #=> 14
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on comment clarification:

```
inputs.sample.map(&:to_i).select(&:odd?).sum
```

For giggles, this is the fastest method I could find:

```
inputs.sample.map(&:to_i).sum {|e| e * ( e % 2 )}
```

Comment: Btw, you might be surprised that doing the two `to_i`s takes longer than running through the list twice.

Comment: Still slower because now you have a stack allocation and GC.

Comment: I can't get faster than `.map(&:to_i).inject(0) {|sum,e| sum + e * ( e % 2 )}` (nor harder to read ;)

Comment: Actually I lied, `.map(&:to_i).sum {|e| e * ( e % 2 )}` - saved another stack allocation :)

Comment: `.sum {|e| (n =e.to_i).odd? ? n : 0 }` seems +/- equally as fast. [Benchmarks](https://replit.com/@engineersmnky/HotNotedActionscript#main.rb).  Remember `map` is allocating a new `Array`. Either way unless the list is substantial the hit it nominal.

Comment: Ah sorry, I'd only tried that capturing in the `inject`, not in a `sum`. Very nice. Not quite as quick as the sum/mod - but very close and a clear 2nd place.

Comment: Yeah, on lists 10 elements or shorter, it's a crap shoot which is better (actually I see your capture perform better more often than not), as the list grows the sum/mod gets better and better. 100 elements I never see it lose.

Comment: Heh, that interim var still slows that one down vs map.sum. See the allocation/GC of the array is just once, that var has to be allocated and GCed once per element (which is why I think it outperforms for shorter arrays).

Answer (score 1):

If we go into a shooting match on speed, I think this is even faster as it sidesteps an unnecessary `to_i` conversion in case the number is even.

```
inputs.sample.sum { |n| n.getbyte(-1).odd? ? n.to_i : 0 } }
```

Running a benchmark on all the supplied answers yields the following:

```
require 'benchmark'
require 'benchmark/ips'

nums = 100.times.map { rand(100).to_s }

Benchmark.ips do |x|
  x.report('simple') { nums.map(&:to_i).select(&:odd?).sum  }
  x.report('fast')   { nums.map(&:to_i).sum { |e| e * ( e % 2 ) } }
  x.report('odd')    { nums.sum { |e| e.to_i.odd? ? e.to_i : 0 } }
  x.report('ascii')  { nums.sum { |n| n.getbyte(-1).odd? ? n.to_i : 0 } }
  x.compare!
end
```

Output:

```
ruby 3.3.0 (2023-12-25 revision 5124f9ac75) [x86_64-linux]
Warming up --------------------------------------
              simple     2.873k i/100ms
                fast     2.706k i/100ms
                 odd     3.753k i/100ms
               ascii     4.090k i/100ms
Calculating -------------------------------------
              simple     21.038k (±22.9%) i/s -    100.555k in   5.013970s
                fast     28.255k (±26.4%) i/s -    132.594k in   5.003179s
                 odd     35.939k (±25.9%) i/s -    168.885k in   5.064407s
               ascii     56.739k (±20.7%) i/s -    269.940k in   5.013879s

Comparison:
               ascii:    56739.0 i/s
                 odd:    35939.2 i/s - same-ish: difference falls within error
                fast:    28255.1 i/s - 2.01x  slower
              simple:    21038.4 i/s - 2.70x  slower
```

Comment: Nice comparison, but I don't think performance issues are the OP's main concern :)

Comment: Very nice optimization. So interesting that on an M1 Mac I get much closer results: fast ~ 1.15x, odd: ~ 1.2x and simple: ~ 1.5x.

Comment: @smathy Another interesting note is that on Ruby 2.5.1 the same code runs significantly faster. About 20% faster. Pretty big difference. Very curious as it seems Ruby 3 is not always the best pick for speed. At least with simple tasks. Might be different in Rails type complex environments.

Comment: That is interesting @Casper, yeah. I guess like you said, other gains necessitated some tradeoffs (or perhaps they were just inadvertent, obviously we're talking about very small real world timeframes here).